# Rails new ActiveRecord build based on triangulation of two required 1:n resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, one-to-many, ruby-on-rails-7

*(Sorry if this has been addressed before, can't find it.)*

Let's say I've got three tables. I'll keep it simple (`P = Post`, `C = Comment` and `U = User`, but not what I'm actually developing): `P ||-> C <-|| U`, where `P` can have many `C`s, and `U` can have many `C`s. I've got my resource routes setup as `Ps/[:p_id]/Us/[:u_id]/cs/[:c_id]`. I need to create a `/new` `C`. From my understanding, typically if I was only building `C` from only `P` or `U`, I would just generate it from an `P.c.build`/`U.c.build`. But since I need both, and neither `A` nor `C` are directly hierarchical to each other, I'm trying to understand how to do this. I need three things:

1. Appropriate `*_path` helper generated somehow with a `new_p_u_c(@P, @U)`
2. Necessary `.build` alternative for triangulating both `P` and `U` with `C`.
3. Necessary `form_with`:

   1. `model:` with `@P` and `@U`
   2. `url:` `*_path` create helper (`p_u_cs(@P, @U)`).
   3. Question: Do I use hidden input fields to store `P` and `U`, is will that be automatically generated within the `forms_with`'s `<form>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this, hope it helps.

1. It was indeed as simple as I had posed it: `new_p_u_c_path(p_id: @P.id, u_id: @U.id)`. I wasn't aware that the paths helper was capable of dynamically accepting multiple arguments. **Precautions:**

   1. Pass them in the exact order as the route resources or (preferably) pass in the named arguments as shown above.
   2. If you don't use named arguments above and you're using a nice URL gem (I'm using `friendly_id`), you'll need to pass in the `@P.id` specifically instead of `@P`, or else the path helper won't be able to find it.
2. I only used `@P.c.build` for this. It worked, but I'm not sure if it is even necessary at this point, since the only thing I needed was the `@P.id`, so see below...
3. I passed in my `form_with(model: @C, ...)`

   1. Because the `/new` route already contained the @P.id and @U.id, the `hidden_field` automatically accepted `p_id` and `u_id` since I had my models setup with appropriate chaining logic.
   2. `p_u_cs_path` worked without passing any additional model arguments (again, see **3.1.** above).
   3. I don't think this is necessary, now I think about it. The URL passed in **3.2.** above should already include the IDs that rails will automatically parse.